# Draw hole in solid shape using x3d/vrml

Tags: x3d, vrml, x3dom, wrl

I'm new to x3d/vrml and I'm trying figure out how to punch a hole in a solid shape. For example, a 6x6x2 cube with a smaller 2x2x2 cube in the middle to create a hollow shape.  I have tried extrusion and indexedFaceSet without success. I haven't  found any tutorials that show me how to do this. Therefore, A working example would be useful to me as well as others .

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't create this kind of shapes manually. Of course it is possible to use the IndexedFaceSet node in order to achieve this but it's much better and easier to use a tool (e.g. 3D Studio Max) where you can create shapes using a graphical interface. Then you export the file to X3D or VRML or whatever and you'll see the IndexedFaceSet there and possibly the complexity of the node (I mean the node values which are nearly impossible to determine by yourself).

In your specific case you could use 4 cubes that are intersecting and leaving a hole in the middle...this would be just a tricky solution.